# CreatedDate in user's local timezone

Tags: datetime

I am trying to convert salesforce standard field CreatedDate to logged-in user's timezone. I am using following code

```
Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(a.CreatedDate.dateGmt(),a.CreatedDate.timeGmt());
```

But this is not giving right result.
for e.g. I have created a record at `11/12/2012 12:50 PM (in GMT+5:30)`. Now when another user (in GMT-5:00) logs into the system and run the above code in developer console then he should see `11/12/2012 2:20 AM` but he sees `11/12/2012 5:50 AM`.

What I am doing wrong? Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the method you're using, [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) says the returned date is in the GMT Timezone.

This should do it

```
Datetime GMTDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(2011,6,1,12,1,5);
String strConvertedDate = GMTDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'America/New_York');
// Date is converted to the new time zone and is adjusted for daylight saving time. 

System.assertEquals('06/01/2011 08:01:05', strConvertedDate);
```

You can get the User's Timezinesidkey via a query to use dynamically per user

```
[select timezonesidkey from user]
```

Comment: I tried Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstanceGMT(a.CreatedDate.dateGmt(),a.CreatedDate.timeGmt()); But this is also not working.

Comment: And you invoked format on it as above? With the appropriate Timezone string?

Comment: No, actually my users can be in different timezones and formatting I want according to locale. Actually this final date I want to render using JavaScript. I want to make it general.

Comment: You can use select timezonesidkey from user where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()

Comment: Since I am using Javascript to render to datetime field. So I want to just pass datetime field in current logged-in user's timezone. Fomrat method will return string and that will not of any use.

Comment: I'm afraid http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/salesforce-timezone-issue/3948#3948 might be the only other solution.

Comment: you are right. it seems like I have to write own method to convert it.

Comment: @doga - you got solution to this problem?. Am also facing the same problem