# How do we get current time of the logged in user?

Tags: visualforce

I need to capture the current users current time in a VF page. Is there a way to capture that info in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind having the date in there:

```
System.now().format()
```

Answer (score 8):

Spring '13 will have a TimeZone class.  You'll be able to get the timezone for the current user and do whatever math you need based on its offset from GMT.

Comment: @prady - you can expect Spring '13 around early February '13.

Comment: Josh: please do not add signatures to your post. http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191/regards-me-bye-bye-or-not-to-bye-bye

Answer (score 2):

System.Now should give you the Current time and display to the User in his local current time Zone .

Other approach is to get the locale using userinfo.getlocale

1)Maintain an offset in custom setting

2)From GMT time you can set the Offset.

I would say that simply system.Now gets you time in the Time Zone of the User

Comment: Does System.now return in usertime zone? As per documentation it says "Returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone." http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/datetime-input-field-cast-to-another-timezone
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/salesforce-timezone-issue
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/createddate-in-users-local-timezone

Comment: I have added links from previous discussions on this topic .Use the Userinfo.getlocale and format accordingly.