# How to get current time of logged in Salesforce user using Salesforce API?

Tags: metadata-api, c#, .net, timezone, partner-wsdl

I have a C# .NET Windows application.
I am using the Partner API to interact with Salesforce.
I want to get the current date and time based on logged in user's timezone in my .NET Windows application.

Basically, in my Windows application, I am fetching data from Salesforce using the API and printing that data into a Word file.
In the Word file, I want the current date and time to display, but the current date and time should be based on the Salesforce User's timezone.

Comment: This might help - [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/how-do-we-get-current-time-of-the-logged-in-user)

Comment: This will not help because I want current date and time of logged in user in my c# application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is it that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login to an org using the [Partner WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner.htm) and the SOAP API [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) function, you can access the user's time zone using the resulting [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) object:

```
login["result"]["userInfo"]["userTimeZone"] // America/Mazatlan
```

Notice that the time zone is formatted using the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) naming convention.

Since you are using C# .NET, I would recommend using the [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) API for .NET, which will help you obtain the current time from the time zone string returned in the result:

```
var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Mazatlan"];
var zoned = local.InZoneLeniently(zone);
```